# Фреймворк для web-приложения

Tags: framework, php

Встал вопрос выбора PHP фреймворка для web-приложения. В данный момент есть 2 фаворита CI и Yii. Основное требование к приложению это работа с большими объёмами данных, СУБД будет использоваться Oracle, для интерфейсной части в основном jQuery с плагином jqGrid. Хотелось бы услышать мнения людей которые разрабатывали большие, масштабируемые приложения на каком либо из этих фреймворков.

Comment: Вместо ``CI`` посоветовал бы ``Kohana``

Answer (score 3):

CI однозначно не годится для решения больших задач. С Yii будет попроще, в принципе можно писать на нем, существенных проблем не должно быть, если писать по уму. Есть поддержка Oracle, работа с БД реализована очень хорошо, есть валидаторы. Кроме того view с классом CHtml очень хорошо реализован, не будет проблем чтобы строить таблицы и всевозможные выводы информации.
Еще посоветовал бы посмотреть в сторону Symfony 2, он больше подходит для сложных задач, но он сложнее чем Yii. В Sf используется Doctrine для работы с БД, так же есть фичи типа валидаторов, форм билдеров, используется шаблонизатор twig, но можно прикрутить любой другой.
Посмотрите, какой из них вам ближе. Yii проще изучить, Symfony сложнее, но он гораздо мощнее.